# How to generate links with RESTful routes on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I am having a problem with a button that links to the "New" action on the current controller named "Clients".

When clicked it show a Rails Routing Error:

> No route matches [POST] "clients/new"

This is the code that I'm using that produces the error:

```
<%= button_to("New Client", new_client_path, :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right add-button" ) %>
```

If I change the path to `clients_path`, like this:

```
<%= button_to("New Client", clients_path, :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right add-button" ) %>
```

I then get the following error:

> Unknown action. The action 'create' could not be found for ClientsController

Controller actions new and create:

```
def new
  @client = Client.new
end

def create
  @client = Client.new(client_params)

  if @client.save
    flash[:notice] = "Client added succesfully."
    redirect_to client_path(@client)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

The routes.rb file contains the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'clients/index'

  get 'clients/show'

  get 'clients/new'

  get 'clients/edit'

  get 'clients/delete'

  resources :clients

end
```

Right now `clients` is the only resource I have created.  What am I missing to create links with ease using RESTful routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things need to change to make this work for you.  First, your routes are redundant and conflicting with Rails convention.  You should remove all of the `get` routes and just use the `resources` routes.  This is all that you need for your Clients routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    # notice, no "get" routes

    resources :clients
end
```

Next, `button_to` defaults to a `POST` method, so you have to override it's method when using it with a `GET` route.  See the [button_to API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) for more information.

Try this, instead:

```
<%= button_to("New Client", new_client_path, { method: :get, :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right add-button" } ) %>
```

Note that `button_to`, like many of the ActionView form helpers, accepts 2 separate hashes, the first being `options`, and the second being `html_options`.  It's important to separate the hash values, or you won't get the behavior that you're looking for.  The `method` and `class` options go in `html_options`.  If you only have one Hash of options (curly brackets are optional) in your call, Ruby will assign them to the *last hash argument*; you can explicitly supply all hashes to make it clear to the reader of your code what you intended, like this:

```
<%= button_to("New Client", new_client_path, {}, { method: :get, :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right add-button" } ) %>
```

Last, the attempt to use the `clients_path` route helper resulted in a path for the `ClientController#index` method (e.g. `/clients`), accompanied by a seemingly unrelated the error about a `create` method.  The `create` action is the `POST` route with the same URL path as the `index` action.  If you look at the output of `rake routes` for this resource, you'll see the following:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
     clients GET    /clients(.:format)          clients#index
             POST   /clients(.:format)          clients#create
  new_client GET    /clients/new(.:format)      clients#new
 edit_client GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format) clients#edit
      client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)      clients#show
             PATCH  /clients/:id(.:format)      clients#update
             PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)      clients#update
             DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)      clients#destroy
```

See how both `clients` (under the "Prefix") matches `GET` for the path `/clients`, and directly below that, there's an unnamed entry for `POST` to the same `/clients` path.  To the far right, you can see that the `GET` method routes to the `clients#index` action, while the `POST` method routes to the `clients#create` action.

In this case, the default method of `button_to` is `POST`, which was attempting to route to the `clients#create` action, which is not what you wanted to do.  You should almost never directly send anything to the `create`, `update`, or `destroy` methods, and on the few occasions that your do, you'll do it very deliberately, and with good the knowledge that it's abnormal (not incorrect, just abnormal) Rails usage.

Comment: This solved my promblem but had to make some changes, instead of `<%= button_to("New Client", clients_path, { method: :get }, { :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right add-button" } ) %>`, I had to modify the route from `clients_path` to `new_client_path` and method and class inside the same braces because of an invalid number of arguments error. It ended up working like this: `<%= button_to("New Client", new_client_path,{ method: :get, class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right add-button' } ) %>`. Please edit the answer to mark as answered.

Comment: @JorgeCuevas Great feedback, and thanks for letting me know!  I've updated the answer and added just a little more explanation about the two hashes for `button_to`.  The `new_client_path` issue was a copy/paste error, and the issue with hash options was a mis-reading of the documentation.  Those are sorted out now, and ready for you to confirm.  Thanks!

Comment: Everything seems fine, hopefully this will help others with similar issues in the future. Thanks for your help Michael, marking as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your `routes.rb` and make sure that you have added `resources :clients`.

You should also take a look at the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and see that you're calling your route incorrectly.

Ex. `clients_new_path` should be `new_client_path`

If you make both of these changes and still have an issue. It looks like the error will be in your **ClientsController**.

Make sure that you have added the `create` action.

```
def create
@client = Client.new(client_params)

if @client.save
  flash[:notice] = 'App successfully created!'
  redirect_to client_path(@client)
else
  flash[:error] = @app.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
  render 'new'
end
```

end

Comment: The routes.rb file includes resources :clients, allong with the get routes generated automatically for each view. I tried changing to new_client_path but it shows exactly the same routing error message.

Comment: I had it but was empty. Filled it but shows the same error. Am I missing something on the routes file?

Comment: Added the Controller and the routes.rb file to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way:

```
<%= button_to("New Client", new_client_path, :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right add-button" ) %>
```

You have to use "client", not "clients" to create a single client

Comment: Already tried as the prior question suggested, still shows the same error when clicking. Edited the post so that it shows the current state of the issue.

Comment: Can you post your client_conroller.rb?

Comment: Added it to the original post.